`dart run` not locating Flutter SDK
I'm developing a Flutter project for Android. From the base project directory, when I run dart run build_runner build, or even dart run on it's own, I get the following error:

Because (name) depends on flutter_test from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.

I ran flutter pub run build_runner build, which didn't give the same error. However, I'd like to use dart run since flutter pub run is deprecated. Why can't Dart find the Flutter SDK?
Info:

Flutter Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

Dart SDK version: 3.5.3 (stable)

/usr/lib/flutter/bin is in PATH.

which dart gives /usr/lib/flutter/bin/dart.

which flutter gives /usr/lib/flutter/bin/flutter.

local.properties has flutter.sdk=/usr/lib/flutter.

Checked Dart SDK locating and found flutter package resolve location in .dart_tool/package_config.json: /usr/lib/flutter/packages/flutter.

All other operations have completed successfully. My Flutter Doctor is:


[✓] Flutter (Channel , 3.24.3, on Arch Linux 6.11.3-arch1-1, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources

